# jPlayer is not working on Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, jplayer

I am using jPlayer in my MVC c# website, some of my clients are trying to use the website on their Tablet, but it sounds like jPlayer is not working on Android. I understand that Android is not supporting flash player anymore, but I can see there are some Androidfix function in the jPlayer.min.js file. I tested the jPlayer on two tablets one with Andriod 4.4 and another one with 4.3 even the Demo players in the jPlayer website did not work. Is there anyway to make it work or is there any other music players that I can use in my MVC website and it works on Android tablets?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

the jPlayer group is aware of this issue.
Check it out here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_source=digest&utm_medium=email/#!topic/jplayer/BoVUNok0yl4

I'd say check for updates in the next couple days.

-Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

If you download latest jPlayer version 2.7.0, you can comment out line 1827, and it will work. Not sure, if it breaks old versions of android browsers, or Google Chrome (Checked on 4 devices, with different version of browsers, still works.)

```
// Setup the Android Fix - Only for HTML audio.
if($.jPlayer.platform.android) {
   //self.androidFix.setMedia = true;
}
```